# Why does images in Google spreadsheet often change their place?

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently working with Google Script which accepts the user input and store in the other spreadsheet. This logic works ok but to facilitate this, I have created a form like provision on my worksheet and placed some images which look like buttons. When I (and other collaborators) open this spreadsheet, we often observe that images are not on their place as shown below,

[image]

Note: See above, buttons (images) 'Get Case Details' & 'Deletegate Tasks' are not on their original positions. Ideally, they should appear as below,

[image]

As a workaround, I just go to some other tab/worksheet and come back to mine which shows the image location correctly.

I checked [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/cF5Ng5FMS6I) on Google Doc forum but looks like a known issue, no answer yet.

Does anyone have any idea? Has anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the discussion that you linked, there a lot of other similar reports over the years on the Google Docs Help Forum and other places on the web.

One alternative is to increase the whitespace around the buttons. Another alternative is to use another UI element like custom menus, a side panel or dialogs.

Comment: Yes, putting same functions as custom menus solves this problem to some extent, especially for users who have got some resolution issues with the screen, thanks Ruben